# Apache Airflow getting exception details of operator in on_failure_callback method

Tags: airflow

Hi i am new to Apache Airflow and using on_failure_callback to handle failure of task. But i want to know following things:

1. Is there any way to get type of exception raised by operator in on_failure_callback method?

This is needed because i wanted to push exception details to xcoms and use it in next operator/task.

so in short is there any way to get exception details of operator and use it in downstream tasks for some logical processing.

Please provide help on how to implement it in code.